# Custom deployment with Azure template

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to create a virtual machine from a template in Azure, there are two fields which is blocking me (CIDR field), can someone please have a look into it. unable to by-pass the notion.

[image]

Comment: template:
,
        "addressPrefixes": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "subnets": {
            "type": "String"
        },


parameters:

    "addressPrefixes": {
      "value": "10.0.0.0/24"
    },
    "subnets": {
      "value": "[{\"name\":\"default\",\"properties\":{\"addressPrefix\":\"10.0.3.0/24\"}}]"
    },
    "publicIpAddressName": {
      "value": "cloudblue-vm1-ip"
    },

Answer (score 1):

you must specify you address as a string, not an array:

```
"10.0.0.0/24"
```

not sure about the second one, probably the same issue

CIDR: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Comment: ok, String is working for Address-prefixes but not for subnets 
alert ([object Object])

Comment: well, you'd need to show your template, i have no idea what you have there

Comment: i dont think it will work like that, you are not supposed to send in raw json, you need to rework it into some for of loop, if you want it to be extensible\extendable

Comment: that might work if you wrap if with `json()` at line https://github.com/RajuTanti/azure-template/blob/master/template.json#L141

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at question, comment and an answer that was provided.

First the problem why you template errored out was because of the **values** that you put in the template. If you do not specify a value you should be able to just put the information like 10.0.0.0/24 when filling out template and that will work.

Note that the **subnets** section is only asking for CIDR notation for subnet range.